# How to design a 'bundle' discount for a supermarket checkout?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm working on an exercise to create a supermarket design with various discounts for the products. Examples of discounts are:

- Buy x amount of an item to get y free
- Buy y amount of an item for $y
- Buy item x and item y for $z

The first two discounts I have managed to create. But since the discount is calculated against the *basket item*, I'm struggling to see how I can get the discount to apply to more than one products. I could create a brand new item and label it "x and y" but that feels a bit like cheating. Please advise

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Item {

    private final String sku;
    private final BigDecimal unitPrice;

    public Item(String sku, BigDecimal unitPrice) {
        this.sku = sku;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public BigDecimal getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }
}
```

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class BasketItem {

    private final Item item;
    private int quantity;
    private final Discount discount;

    public BasketItem(Item item, Discount discount) {
        this.item = item;
        this.discount = discount;
        this.quantity = 1;
    }

    public BasketItem(Item item, Discount discount, int quantity) {
        this.item = item;
        this.discount = discount;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void increment() {
        this.quantity++;
    }

    public BigDecimal calculateSubTotal() {
        return item.getUnitPrice().multiply(new BigDecimal(quantity));
    }

    public BigDecimal calculateDiscount() {
        return discount.apply(this);
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

}
```

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public interface Discount {

    BigDecimal apply(BasketItem item);

}
```

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.security.InvalidParameterException;

public class BuyXGetYFree implements Discount {

    private final int buy;
    private final int free;

    public BuyXGetYFree(int buy, int free) {
        if (buy < 1) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Can't buy less than 1 item");
        }

        if (free < 1) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Can't free less than 1 item for free");
        }

        if (free > buy) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("The free amount must not exceed the purchased amount");
        }

        this.buy = buy;
        this.free = free;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal apply(BasketItem basketItem) {

        int quantity = basketItem.getQuantity();
        BigDecimal unitPrice = basketItem.getItem().getUnitPrice();

        if (buy + free > quantity && quantity > buy) {
            return unitPrice.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(quantity - buy));
        }

        int multiplier = quantity / (buy + free);
        int forFree = multiplier * free;
        return unitPrice.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(forFree));
    }
    
}
```

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class NoDiscount implements Discount {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal apply(BasketItem item) {
        return BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }
}
```

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.security.InvalidParameterException;

public class BuyXForY implements Discount{

    int buy;
    BigDecimal pay;

    public BuyXForY(int buy, BigDecimal pay) {
        if (buy < 1) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Buy must be at least 1");
        }
        this.buy = buy;
        this.pay = pay;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal apply(BasketItem item) {
        int quantity = item.getQuantity();

        if (quantity < buy) {
            return BigDecimal.ZERO;
        }

        int multiplier = quantity / buy;
        int remainder = quantity % buy;

        BigDecimal buyAtDiscountedPrice = new BigDecimal(multiplier).multiply(pay);
        BigDecimal buyAtNormalPrice = new BigDecimal(multiplier).multiply(new BigDecimal(remainder));
        BigDecimal normalPrice = new BigDecimal(quantity).multiply(item.getItem().getUnitPrice());

        return normalPrice.subtract(buyAtDiscountedPrice.add(buyAtNormalPrice));
    }
}
```

```
public class DiscountAssignment {

    private final Discount discount;
    private final Item item;

    public DiscountAssignment(Discount discount, Item item) {
        this.discount = discount;
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Discount getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

}
```

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Checkout {

    private final List<BasketItem> basketItems;
    private final List<DiscountAssignment> discountAssignments;

    public Checkout(List<DiscountAssignment> discountAssignments) {
        this.basketItems = new ArrayList<>();
        this.discountAssignments = discountAssignments;
    }

    public void scan(Item item) {
        Optional<BasketItem> basketItemOptional = basketItems.stream().filter(basketItem -> basketItem.getItem().equals(item)).findFirst();

        if (basketItemOptional.isPresent()) {
            basketItemOptional.get().increment();
            return;
        }

        Optional<DiscountAssignment> discountsToApply = discountAssignments.stream().filter(discountAssignment -> discountAssignment.getItem().equals(item)).findFirst();

        if (discountsToApply.isPresent()) {
            basketItems.add(new BasketItem(item, discountsToApply.get().getDiscount()));
        } else {
            basketItems.add(new BasketItem(item, new NoDiscount()));
        }
    }

    public BigDecimal total() {
        System.out.println(basketItems);

        return basketItems.stream()
                .map(BasketItem::calculateSubTotal)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
                .subtract(basketItems.stream()
                        .map(BasketItem::calculateDiscount)
                        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add));
    }

}
```

A quick test outputs a total cost of 4

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item drink = new Item("Drink", new BigDecimal(1));
        Item candy = new Item("Candy", new BigDecimal(1));

        DiscountAssignment buyOneGetOneFreeDiscount = new DiscountAssignment(new BuyXGetYFree(1, 1), drink);
        DiscountAssignment buyTwoForOneDollar = new DiscountAssignment(new BuyXForY(2, BigDecimal.ONE), candy);

        Checkout checkout = new Checkout(List.of(buyOneGetOneFreeDiscount, buyTwoForOneDollar));
        checkout.scan(drink);
        checkout.scan(drink);
        checkout.scan(drink);
        checkout.scan(drink);
        checkout.scan(candy);
        checkout.scan(candy);

        System.out.println("Total cost: " + checkout.total());
    }

}
```

I tried created a brand new bundle item. But each item must be scanned individually.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having those special items I'd suggest you try the following:

- Provide rules for discounts like you're already doing. Define a hierarchy of rules since you might not want to combine discounts (e.g. "buy x, get y free" and "buy x and pay only y")
- Add "discount" items if a rule applies, e.g.

  - "buy x, get y free" -> add a discount of "free_items * item_price", e.g. "buy 6 and get 2 free" with a price of 4.99 -> position with value "-9.98"
  - "buy x for price y" -> add discount of "items * (item_price - discounted_price)"
  - "buy item x and get item y for price z" -> add discount item for "y" with a value of "amount_of_y * (price_of_y - z)"

In the end the receipt could thus look like this (with each line being an item):

```
Item          Amount Unit price  Total
======================================
Coke               4       0.99   3.96
Coke 4 for 3       1      -0.99  -0.99  //item added by the "buy 4 get 1 free" rule
Snickers           2       1.95   3.90
Snickers 1.70      2      -0.25  -0.50  //item added by the "get Snickers for 1.70" rule
Beer              11       1.50  16.50
Chips              1       2.69   2.69      
Chips (for 6 beer) 1      -2.69  -2.69  //item added by the "buy 6 beer and get 1 bag of chips" rule, applied once 1 bag of chips was in the cart  
======================================
Total                            22.87
```

This has the advantage of showing the original price as well as the discounts that were added. Of course the order of elements could be different if needed but I'd basically maintain it like this:

```
List<Item> basketItems; //items the customer added with the original price
List<Item> discountItems; //items created by rules to show the discounts that were applied

List<Item> finalItems; //a combination of basketItems and discountItems to show in the output - either just concatenate or sort by item, group, price etc. as needed
```